# Swift 1/2 UITextView suggestion by tag "@" or "#"

Tags: ios, swift, textview, swift2

i'm trying to put suggestion on a textview like on instagram, if you type #Hello he suggest you hello and other similar hashtag, i'm able to do it in a TextField, how can i do it in a TextView? I saw this project on github and i tried with this: https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController/tree/swift-example But I can't make it work on swift, tried for around 3 hours... How can I do that ? Do you have any ideas ? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can compile objective-c files together with swift via Bridging-Header file

Comment: yes but then ? that isn't a guide on how to put the code to get suggestion in swift :\

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org)? If not, you definitely should. It's very simple co connect any Objective-C pod to your swift project.

Skip first 4 steps if you already got your cocoapods setup

1. Download cocoapods if you haven't yet with `sudo gem install cocoapods`
2. Run `pod init` in directory with your project file
3. Add `pod 'SlackTextViewController'` and remove template pods in `PodFile`(was created in project directory)
4. Run `pod install`, close your project in Xcode and open created `.workspace` file
5. Create new `Header` file in your Xcode using `File->New->File` and name it somehow like `Bridging.h`
6. Select top project file of your workspace, select your target and open `Build Settings` tab. Find `Objective-C Bridging Header` and set value with relative path to your `Bridging.h`
7. In your `Bridging.h` add line

`#import "SLKTextViewController.h"`

And then finally build your workspace. Now you you should be able to compile without any errors.

Comment: already tried but i couldn't find the method in swift.. ( I don't know objective c )

Comment: Try `import SLKTextViewController` at header of your file

Comment: yes but then ? that isn't a guide on how to put the code to get suggestion in swift :\